# opening a selectbox with every click on anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
   <a href="" >add Select box</a>
```

what i want is that when i click on anchor tag i should open a selectbox...with every new click a new selectbox should appear...suppose if i click on anchor tag first i should display a selectbox...when i again click on it it should again open a selectbox...but i want this in jquery...so can anyone help me with this??

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        ???

 </script>
```

Comment: well i have done it with javascript but no idea how to do it with jquery

Comment: find on SO here, you can find many posts which is aleready answered. Try it on. [Good reference to start](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Please post you Javascript code.

Comment: i searched for it but not getting desirable result

Comment: if you know javascript then jQuery is not that hard to learn. first try to learn basics.

Comment: actually the selectboxes i am talking about would be fetching data from database...but javascript and php cannot work together...so searching for a new way...that's y asking about jquery

Comment: You are wrong. Javascript and PHP can work together. Lookup in Google for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

http://jsfiddle.net/wWhZL/

```
var arr = [{
    val: 1,
    text: 'Option 1'
}, {
    val: 2,
    text: 'Option 2'
}];

$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
        $(arr).each(function () {
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it will work great thanxx...but tell me one thing we are opening multiple selectboxes ...will it be possible to fetch options from database for each selectbox??

Comment: Yes of course, but that's a very different question. I would suggest ask a new question about it. But you should probably read some tutorials first. Good luck!

Comment: thankuu so much for the help

Comment: but sir i accepted your answer....

Comment: I know. You accepted it while I was writing that :)

Comment: sir i have a problem can you please help me???

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery code:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    $('body').append($('<select></select>'));
});
```

UPDATE: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85zAh/1/)

Comment: at anchor tag do i have to write onclick event

Comment: Yes. Checkout the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/85zAh/ and make sure to readup on the tutorials.

Comment: when i am clicking on the anchor tag selectbox is coming and getting vanished

Comment: @user3181292 Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85zAh/1/ added the missing `href="#"`. I would recomment not to use a link, you are not linking anywere. Use a `<button>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check with below Code:

     $('#add').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $select = $('<select></select>');
                    $select.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "0").text("--- Select ---"));
                    $(this).append($select);
                });

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add" >add Select box</a>
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/8k75T/

Answer (score 0):

I have one demo please check the link

http://jsfiddle.net/ph5Ya/1/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="openSelectBox">add Select box</a> | <a href="#" id="closeSelectBox">Close Select box</a>

<br>
<select name="country_id" id="country_id" tabindex="1">
    <optgroup label="North America">
        <option value="1">USA</option>
        <option value="9">Canada</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Europe">
        <option value="2">France</option>
        <option value="3">Spain</option>
        <option value="6">Bulgaria</option>
        <option value="7" disabled="disabled">Greece</option>
        <option value="8">Italy</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Asia" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="5">Japan</option>
        <option value="11">China</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="4">Brazil</option>
    <option value="10">South Africa</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $("#country_id").selectbox();
    $("#openSelectBox").click(function () {
        $("#country_id").selectbox("open");
    });

    $("#closeSelectBox").click(function () {
        $("#country_id").selectbox("close");
    });

});
```